# copy contents from one file to another file(dont overwrite if exists)

Tags: java

I have written a java code to copy contents from 1 file to other. here what it is said is that if the file exists it shoudn't be over written. i have used that case so if it exists it doesn't overwrite but it erases the entire content of the second file... kindly help me with the code. i have shared the question and the code here. kindly help!!

QUESTION:

java program which take source file and destination file as input as command line arguments. It copies the source file contents to destination file.  If source file does not exist, it should give appropriate message to use.  If destination file does not exist, it should be created.  If it exists, program should ask that, “whether you want to overwrite?(Yes/No”. 
On the basis of user choice, appropriate action should be taken.

JAVA CODE:

```
package com.files.file_handle;
import java.io.Closeable;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class FileCopy { 
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException { 
        Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in); 
        FileReader fr = null; 
        FileWriter fw = null; 
        try { 
            System.out.println("enter a source file which exists"); 
            String file1=s.next(); 
            fr = new FileReader(file1); 
            System.out.println("enter a destination file"); 
            String file2=s.next();

            File f2=new File(file2); 
            if(!f2.exists()) { 
                fw = new FileWriter(file2); 
                f2.createNewFile(); 
                int c = fr.read(); 
                while(c!=-1) { 
                    fw.write(c); 
                    c = fr.read(); 
                } 
                System.out.println("file copied successfully"); 
            } else { 
                fw = new FileWriter(file2); 
                System.out.println("do you want to overwrite? enter 'yes' or 'no'..."); 
                char ans = s.next().charAt(0);

                if(ans=='N'||ans=='n') { 
                    System.out.println("couldnot enter data"); 
                } else { 
                    int c = fr.read(); 
                    while(c!=-1) { 
                        fw.write(c); 
                        c = fr.read(); 
                    } 
                    System.out.println("file updated successfully"); 
                } 
            } 
        } catch(IOException e) { 
            System.out.println("file coudn't be found"); 
        } finally { 
            close(fr); 
            close(fw); 
        } 
    } 
    public static void close(Closeable stream) { 
        try { 
            if (stream != null) { 
                stream.close(); 
            } 
        } catch(IOException e) { //... } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by 'not getting updated'?

Comment: Use [Edit] to add your source code to your question.

Comment: @ayav you can update your question, you can put your code there not in comments :)

Comment: @ayav try to put it in the question body

Comment: @ayav well then you should format it properly. which program are you writing the code in?

Comment: As for your question: "here what it is said is that if the file exists it shoudn't be over written" - just do what it says: check if the file exists (there is a method `exists()` in `File`) and maybe even check the file's size (if that's a requirement) and act accordingly.

Comment: @Thomas yes i have used exists...but it erases the contents

Comment: System.out.println("do you want to overwrite? enter 'yes' or 'no'..."); 
                char ans = s.next().charAt(0);

                if(ans=='N'||ans=='n') { 
                    System.out.println("couldnot enter data");

Comment: in this part it should only display the message on console.. but instead it displays and erases the original contant of the file..

Comment: @all Since the code has been added by sonnet, could you please delete your comments on that in order to make problem-related comments visible?

Comment: @ayav it might be the filewriter that you create before asking the user whether to overwrite or not. Closing that might flush it and since it is empty will just erase the file content. Better only create the writer if the content should be overwritten.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code works perfectly, The issue was when open the file in write mode its content will be automatically cleared.

```
import java.io.Closeable;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class FileCopy { 
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException { 
    Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in); 
    FileReader fr = null; 
    FileWriter fw = null; 
    try { 
        System.out.println("enter a source file which exists"); 
        String file1=s.next(); 
        fr = new FileReader(file1); 
        System.out.println("enter a destination file"); 
        String file2=s.next();

        File f2=new File(file2); 
        if(!f2.exists()) { 
            fw = new FileWriter(file2); 
            f2.createNewFile(); 
            int c = fr.read(); 
            while(c!=-1) { 
                fw.write(c); 
                c = fr.read(); 
            } 
            fr.close();
            System.out.println("file copied successfully"); 
        } else { 

            System.out.println("do you want to overwrite? enter 'yes' or 'no'..."); 
            char ans = s.next().charAt(0);

            if(ans=='N'||ans=='n') { 
                fr.close();
            //  fw.close();
                System.out.println("couldnot enter data"); 
            } else { 
                  fw = new FileWriter(file2); 
                int c = fr.read(); 
                while(c!=-1) { 
                    fw.write(c); 
                    c = fr.read(); 
                } 
                fr.close();
                System.out.println("file updated successfully"); 
            } 
        } 
    } catch(IOException e) { 
        System.out.println("file coudn't be found"); 
    } finally { 
        close(fr); 
        close(fw); 
        //fw.close();
    } 
} 
public static void close(Closeable stream) { 
    try { 
        if (stream != null) { 
            stream.close(); 
        } 
    } catch(IOException e) { //... 
        e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: i tried your code after removing error..it stil erases the entire data

Comment: I got it, I am checking it now.

Comment: if we say 'y' den it should overwrite or else it should keep the contents same

Comment: can you explain me where you did the updation?

Comment: initializing/creating the file writer

Comment: Whenever you open the file writer / anything which opens in write mode erases its contents

Comment: You created the FileWriter at wrong place, Whenever you create FileWriter the file will be erased completely and the file pointer is set to the beginning of the file.

Comment: Not a problem!!